# How to solve Visual studio 2019 Setup Error?

Tags: installation, runtime-error, visual-studio-2019

I try to install visual studio 2019 community edition, setup not completed,

screen recorder : https://www.loom.com/share/0dd5ef8a792749a9b8e6023dc9364206

Any help thanks.

Comment: Please include the key information in the question. Watching a video means I cannot copy text for searches.

Comment: @Richard What is key information? I am ready to give anything, could you pls explain  what is key information?

Comment: Error messages and codes shown in the UI, and also in the set up log files.

Comment: May I know where is located set up log filess.

Comment: the installer usually tells you on error.

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? What does `setup not completed` mean? I checked your video but it's too short, I didn't see any normal setup errors there. SO I'm confused if you meet a situation the real setup process doesn't start or it starts but end with error.

Comment: Windows update solve my issue. Thank you for everyone.